# Replace url parameter

Tags: jquery

My URL is

```
   /home/?tx_besijobs_pi1[pointer]=2&cHash=749431ca0340bf2344cc90704f79570f
```

My jquery code contain

```
    var pntr = getUrlVars()["tx_besijobs_pi1[pointer]"];
```

from which I am getting pointer value as 1,2,3,...

I have to change ***pointer value to 0*** on next Tab click. 
My replace code looks like

```
    id =id.replace("[pointer]=pntr", "[pointer]=0");
```

But its not working...

If I am manually giving pointer value

```
    id =id.replace("[pointer]=2", "[pointer]=0");
```

the code will work . How can use "**pntr**" in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use regular expression like:

```
var url = '/home/?tx_besijobs_pi1[pointer]=2&cHash=749431ca0340bf2344cc90704f79570f';
alert( url.replace(/pointer\]=\d{1,}/gi, "pointer]=0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`pntr` is a variable, so it should be outside the quotation marks.

Try this:

```
id = id.replace("[pointer]=" + pntr, "[pointer]=0");
```